# Rewriting Php to javascript to work with iBeacons

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ibeacon

My friend and I wrote a webapp in php for school. The app was supposed to work with Ibeacons but we just figured out that we can't link an external beacon CMS to a form, which was what we were planning on doing. Instead we're thinking of rewriting all the php code that pulls records from the database and shows it on the webpage. If we get rid of the php and compile it to a mobile app with a program like Phonegap we might be able to integrate beacons in the app.

I've been looking everywhere to find an easy way to rewrite the php code to JS server pulls, with no luck. at the moment we're using a local database but we want to transfer it to a server.

What would be the best way to translate the php code? We have no idea how to start.

Here's an example of our PHP code we're trying to rewrite.

```
<?php
session_start();
  include("config.php");
  include("Classes/event.class.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
{
  header('location: login.php');
}
$event = new Event();
$uid = $_SESSION['u_id'];

  if(!empty($_POST))
  {


    $foto = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $event->Foto = $foto;
    $tmp_name = $_FILES ['file']['tmp_name'];
    $error = $_FILES['file']['error'];

    if (!empty($foto)) 
    {
      $location = 'noteimg/';
      if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$foto))
      {

      }
    }
    $event->Title = $_POST['titel'];
    $event->Teaser = $_POST['teaser'];
    $event->Link = $_POST['link'];
    $event->Beacon = $_POST['beacon0'];
    $event->EndDate = $_POST['enddate'];
    $event->save($uid);

  }
?>
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with the translation. Did you have a question?

Comment: I added one. The translation is something we've never done before and we are just looking for a good, but understandable way to do it, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's hard to achieve in an automated approach.

Maybe [php-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-express) module could be useful to directly execute some chunks of php code.

But I thing you should refactor allmost all application structure. Specially all parts regarding routing or dealing with http headers, etc...

Comment: The php code we use is really quite simple though. We just put data in a database and get it out so you can see it. The thing is, when I try to find examples online they're really complicated and for more difficult pieces of php code. I just have no idea how to start translating the code...

Comment: Then better fully translate it to javascript. You will avoid too many headache this way.

Comment: By the way, while translating code across distinct languages, a useful trick (at least for me) is to write a few functions emulating source language ones to be able to run it by simply fix minor syntax differences.

Comment: I'm really confused on how to get to the same result using JS. I've never used JS to get data from a database and print it on a html page. It's all very new to me haha. I really am trying to understand it though.

Comment: Use Express Generator ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator ) and read Express documentation (http://expressjs.com/api.html ). Also take a look of the code generated by express generator. Specially app.js, bin/www and files in /routes. You should start modifying routes/index.js.

Comment: ...also, migrate (if possible) your templates to jade. If they are html with a few php it should be easy with html2jade ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2jade )